# Unable to connect debian to android via bluetooth

Tags: debian, audio, android, pulseaudio, bluetooth

I want to connect my android phone to my debian computer. And to be able to play audio from my phone through the laptops speakers. I have been able to do so in the past on Ubuntu and ElementaryOS (Which is basically Ubuntu.)

On Debian however this for some reason isn't working. The two devices have successfully paired and i can send files to the phone however neither of the devices is showing the other as connected. The Android says "Paired but not connected" while on Debian, the connection switch is disabled.

I didn't really install anything, apart from the non-free firmware-atheros package without which the BT didn't even work this much.. so basically that was a required proprietary driver.

Comment: Suggestion: write more about the used tools, softwares.